# How to use readCSV in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, read.csv

I am trying to read a csv file and iterate the values of the csv file , I am using readCSV for reading the values of csv file . But I am getting the below error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.csv.ReadCSVStep.setFormat() expects class org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat but received class org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:429)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:331)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:272)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:204)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepDescriptorImpl.newInstance(AbstractFileOrTextStepDescriptorImpl.java:24)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepDescriptorImpl.newInstance(AbstractFileOrTextStepDescriptorImpl.java:12)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:302)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
01:24:57    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor229844.invoke(Unknown Source)
01:24:57    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
01:24:57    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
01:24:57    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
01:24:57    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
01:24:57    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
01:24:57    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
01:24:57    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
01:24:57    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
01:24:57    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
01:24:57    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker€0.97.call(Checker.java:180)
01:24:57    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
01:24:57    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:162)
01:24:57    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker€0.97.call(Checker.java:178)
01:24:57    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
01:24:57    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
01:24:57    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
01:24:57    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
01:24:57  Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {file=security.csv, format=Delimiter=<,> QuoteChar=<"> RecordSeparator=<
01:24:57  > EmptyLines:ignored SkipHeaderRecord:false Header:[]} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.csv.ReadCSVStep
```

My jenkinsfile looks like this

```
stage('Init Artifacts') { 
      steps { 
            checkout(scm); 
            script {                
            if (params.ScanStack != '') {   
                    def csv_artifacts = readCSV file: 'security.csv',  format: CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader('ARTIFACT_NAME', 'ARTIFACT_VERSION');
                    
                for (CSVRecord record : csv_artifacts.iterator())      {
                        artifactsList.add(record.toMap())
                    }
                    
                }  
                
                
          }
        }   
    }`
```

It was working fine but after a jenkins upgrade , readCSV has started throwing error . I also see a jenkins issue with similar problem https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58137 but there is no solution to it .
Please help me with this issue , I am trying to fix it since last 6 days .
Jenkins version 2.375.2
Pipeline Utility Steps
Version
2.15.0

Comment: Could anybody please answer the question , I am really struggling with this error for a long time and not able to find a solution .